# Getting dumbbells on knees for the dumbbell benchpress

Tags: bench-press, dumbbells

For doing dumbbell benchpress, I've figured one can simply farmers carry the dumbbells to the narrow end of the bench, but what is the proper form to get it up onto the knees for the position before kicking it back to the chest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're picking them up from the floor, simply lift them up as you would for a deadlift. To get them on your knees, the way I do it is to bend at the hip slightly, like a bent over row, so the end of the dumbell is just above you knee. Then just bend at the knee sitting on the bench, holding the dumbells in position, and they will end up on your knees.

Comment: Ah okay, so partial deadlifttill above knees and rotate dumbbells